# Groovy - ActiveMQConnectionFactory ignores serverUrl

Tags: groovy, activemq-classic

I am using Apache ActiveMQ with Groovy.
I get my connection with this code:

```
connection = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(serverUrl).createConnection();
```

But the parameter serverUrl is ignored. When I use for example an Url that doesn't exists, it just connects to the local Apache MQ.

Why is this so?

I am using this version of the library: `org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:5.7.0`

Best regards,
Peter

Comment: could you please provide the value you are using in `serverUrl`?

Comment: serverUrl = "this should not work";

I am exception that no connection should be established

Comment: well it doesn't ;) glancing at the code at github it looks, like it would just be ignored, if it does not fullfill some form. have you tried a valid one?

Comment: Ok, using a different url prevents the connection to be established, that was what I expected. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` only uses the passed URI, if it resembles an actual valid URL.  If it is totally work it get (silently) ignored.